# Memory error deploying app in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, out-of-memory

I'm trying to deploy a flask API in Google App Engine but faced MemoryError.

When running `gcloud app deploy` I receive the following message via terminal:

```
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build f857cba3-1bf5-4384-acec-f1ee3ba97c8b status: FAILURE.
Build error details: {"error":{"errorType":"BuildError","canonicalCode":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","errorId":"26CADD66","errorMessage":"14 May 2020 13:48:07 INFO     Arguments: ['--parser_script=/usr/local/bin/ftl.par', '--src=', '--entrypoint=', '--name=us.gcr.io/aerospider/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:7e15a1a4-8ddf-4fdb-b668-f8d48552bfa0', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv', '--cache-repository=us.gcr.io/aerospider/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d', '--cache', '--builder-output-path=\"\"', '--additional-directory=/.googleconfig', '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7', '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip', '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG', '--base=us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20200405_3_7_7_RC00']\n14 May 2020 13:48:07 INFO     Unparsed arguments: ['--name=us.gcr.io/aerospider/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:7e15a1a4-8ddf-4fdb-b668-f8d48552bfa0', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv', '--cache-repository=us.gcr.io/aerospider/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d', '--cache', '--builder-output-path=\"\"', '--additional-directory=/.googleconfig', '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7', '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip', '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG', '--base=us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20200405_3_7_7_RC00']\n14 May 2020 13:48:07 INFO     Executing ['/usr/local/bin/ftl.par', '--name=us.gcr.io/aerospider/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:7e15a1a4-8ddf-4fdb-b668-f8d48552bfa0', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv', '--cache-repository=us.gcr.io/aerospider/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d', '--cache', '--builder-output-path=\"\"', '--additional-directory=/.googleconfig', '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7', '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip', '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG', '--base=us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20200405_3_7_7_RC00']\nINFO     FTL version python-v0.17.0\nINFO     Beginning FTL build for python\nINFO     FTL arg passed: virtualenv_dir /env\nINFO     FTL arg passed: ttl 168\nINFO     FTL arg passed: python_cmd /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: virtualenv_cmd virtualenv\nINFO     FTL arg passed: entrypoint None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: exposed_ports None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: pip_cmd /env/bin/python3.7 -m pip\nINFO     FTL arg passed: tar_base_image_path None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: export_cache_stats False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: builder_output_path \"\"\nINFO     FTL arg passed: destination_path /srv\nINFO     FTL arg passed: sh_c_prefix False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: base us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20200405_3_7_7_RC00\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_key_version v0.17.0\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_salt \nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_repository us.gcr.io/aerospider/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d\nINFO     FTL arg passed: venv_cmd /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env\nINFO     FTL arg passed: name us.gcr.io/aerospider/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:7e15a1a4-8ddf-4fdb-b668-f8d48552bfa0\nINFO     FTL arg passed: global_cache False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: upload True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: fail_on_error True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: output_path None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: directory /workspace\nINFO     FTL arg passed: additional_directory /.googleconfig\nINFO     FTL arg passed: verbosity DEBUG\nINFO     starting: full build\nINFO     starting: builder initialization\nINFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20200405_3_7_7_RC00'\nINFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'us.gcr.io/aerospider/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:7e15a1a4-8ddf-4fdb-b668-f8d48552bfa0'\nINFO     builder initialization took 0 seconds\nINFO     starting: build process for FTL image\nINFO     starting: checking_cached_interpreter_layer\nINFO     starting: check python version\nINFO     `python version` full cmd:\n/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 --version\nINFO     `python version` stderr:\n\nINFO     check python version took 0 seconds\nDEBUG   .
```

When checking the build details on GCP I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 54, in main
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/python/builder.py", line 123, in Build
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/layer_builder.py", line 42, in BuildLayer
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/ftl_util.py", line 116, in zip_dir_to_layer_sha
MemoryError
```

My `requirements.txt` is as follows:

```
scikit-learn==0.20.3
pandas==1.0.3
xgboost==1.0.2
fuzzywuzzy==0.18.0
python-Levenshtein==0.12.0
gensim==3.8.1
nltk==3.3
Flask==1.1.2
flask-cors==3.0.7
requests==2.23.0
```

My `app.yaml` is as follows:

```
runtime: python37
instance_class: F4_1G
resources:
  cpu: 3
  memory_gb: 16
  disk_size_gb: 30
```

I tried a lot of configurations related to cpus and memory and none worked.

I think the problem is I'm trying to load a word2vec model with 3.5gb:

`model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('./GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)`

Answer (score 0):

In App Engine the `app.yaml` can use one of the tags between `instance_class` and `resources` as both define the machine type that will be assigned to the app engine instance.

In App Engine Standar the tag used is ´instance_class´ as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref) all the isnstances which have an [instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes) come with 1 GB of disk then it makes scence to be getting an error when trying to upload a file bigger than this 1 GB of storage.

If you want to specify more about the machine type that is going to be used like the memory, disk size etc then you need to deploy in [App Engine Flex] where you can specify the resources tag.

To deploy on flex the `app.yaml` needs to specify that the environment is flex as well as the custom configuration for the instance in this case.

```
runtime: python
env: flex

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

resources:
  cpu: 4
  memory_gb: 16
  disk_size_gb: 30
```

I modified the CPUs from 3 to 4 as this value shall be 1 or an even number.

Consider that App Engine Flex is more expensive than standard and takes more time to deploy.

Sometimes this can send a `Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy.` error, it is expected that it can be thrown, if you get this issue try again some time after and if it is happening again please try deploying the app in a different region.

Comment: Setting up this configuration returns a message saying was not possible to build the instance because some params were missing

Comment: hi, I modified the app.yaml file, as it was missing the runtime_config